# pandoc PDF output, hyphen disappearing?

Tags: compiler-errors, latex, rendering, pandoc

Something odd is happening when I convert my markdown file to PDF with pandoc (using XeLaTeX as engine). When I have anything of the form `5-limit` in my markdown (so basically a number followed by a hyphen followed by a word, usually "limit"), the hypen disappears completely in the rendered PDF (rendering to simply **5limit**). In the terminal, I see that pandoc turns `5-limit` into `5ÔÇælimit` for LaTeX processing, which is incomprehensible to me. Has anyone come across this issue before?

`--` and `---` both render perfectly, and single hyphen `-` also seems to render fine in more typical circumstances. Can't seem to figure out what is happening here...I would find it odd if I have to escape something here, and I can't think of any packages that would be causing this...

Comment: Can you make a [mre]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Did you type the file yourself or did you copy the content from somewhere else? I would check if the character code matches the code for hyphen

Comment: Hi all, the issue was trivial in the end -- apparently those characters just don't exist in the font I was using. Changing the font solved the issue, but just exactly what "5ÔÇæ" is remains an intriguing mystery...